# NullPointerException when initializing VaadinServlet using Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am working on upgrading a Vaadin 8 application to Vaadin 14. I had to manually define an extension of `VaadinServlet` rather than using Vaadin 14's automatic servlet registration, as I need it to be mapped to a specific URL pattern. I am using `web.xml` to configure the servlet in the same way that it was successfully configured for Vaadin 8.

When my servlet is initialized, I get a `ServletException` caused by a `NullPointerException` coming from Vaadin's code. I looked at the source code and I can see that the exception occurs when Vaadin tries to get a `Lookup` instance from the servlet's `ServletContext` and instead it returns null. I found that the `Lookup` instance is supposed to get added to the context in `LookupServletContainerInitializer`, but it appears that this is not happening in my case.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? The stack trace of the `NullPointerException` is below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileFromClassloader(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:341)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileContents(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:311)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.readBuildInfo(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:181)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createInitParameters(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:174)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createDeploymentConfiguration(VaadinServlet.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:190)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:602)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LookupServletContainerInitializer` is a `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` which is supposed to be automatically run by the servlet container during initialization.

There are two typical situations in which this part of initialization is skipped:

- `web.xml` is configured to skip certain steps e.g. because `metadata-complete` is set to true or there's an empty `<absolute-ordering>`.
- The functionality might need to be explicitly enabled if you're embedding a servlet container instead of running it as a standalone server. In the case of Jetty, you need to enable the `AnnotationConfiguration` module and maybe also set the `ContainerIncludeJarPattern` property to include at least the .jar file that includes `VaadinServlet` and related classes.

A third alternative is that you emulate `ServletContainerInitializer` by manually instantiating and invoking the initializers used by Vaadin. It requires a little bit of trial and error to discover exactly which initializers need to be run with what parameters. I created an example for what this might look like in https://github.com/Legioth/vaadin-without-classpath-scanning, but that was before `LookupServletContainerInitializer` was introduced so you would have to take care of that one separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed the example you provided and I no longer get the `NullPointerException`, though I now get a 404 error for one of the resources in `/VAADIN/static/client` and I'm not sure if it is related.
Can you clarify which Vaadin classes I should pass to the `DevModeInitializer`? I see you passed it the class of every component you used in `MainView`. Is it necessary to pass it the class of every type of component I use in my application?

Comment: If you're doing things manually, then you need to look at the `@HandlesTypes` annotation of the `DevModeInitializer` and pass in classes for everything relevant on the application's classpath that implements or is annotated with any of the listed interfaces or annotations. Then repeat the same for all the other `ServletContainerInitializer` subclasses that are part of Vaadin. Or alternatively, configure your servlet container to do that automatically for you instead. `/VAADIN/static/client` might be related to `@PWA`.