# Vaadin 23 application doesn't recognize vaadin-dev-server dependency when running in development mode

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm in the process of upgrading a Vaadin Flow application from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 22. I'm using Gradle 6.9.1 to build the application. When I run the application in Eclipse, I get warnings and errors in the logs identical to those documented in [issue 11982](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11982#issue-1016128382). According to this issue, this initial warning about the `vaadin-dev-server` dependency is the most relevant message:

```
WARN [] [VaadinServletService] [qtp819245704-14] no DevModeHandlerManager implementation found but dev server enabled. Include the com.vaadin.vaadin-dev-server dependency.
```

I have included the dependency in my `build.gradle` file. Here are the dependencies that are relevant to Vaadin:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-core:22.+"
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-dev-server:9.0.0"
}
```

I can see `vaadin-dev-server-9.0.0.jar` in my `Referenced Libraries` within Eclipse along with the other Vaadin `.jar` files. All of them are located in my Gradle cache.

Am I missing something, or is there anything I can do to resolve this issue? Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

Edit: I'm now trying to upgrade the application to Vaadin 23 instead and I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm also getting the webpack error referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71425191/14409144). If it helps, I'm running the project locally using embedded Jetty and I'm manually instantiating and invoking the initializers used by Vaadin as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67529621/14409144).

Comment: How are you running the project and on what server? The vaadin-dev-server dependency is included automatically along with all other jars so the problem is something else

Comment: @ArturSignell I am running the project locally using embedded Jetty.

Comment: The same error message happens when using Karibu for unit tests (despite the dependency to vaadin-dev-server being there). Tests seem to pass fine, though.