# Vaadin 23 Error: Cannot find module '@vaadin/build-status-plugin'

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to upgrade to Vaadin 23 from Vaadin 18. After performing the steps listed on the upgrade instructions I'm having a ton of issues getting the front-end build. The latest blocker is that after starting the app, npm runs, but I see the below error. I checked the node_modules folder and the build-status-plugin folder is a symlink to target\plugins\build-status-plugin, which is empty.

The rest of the node_modules folder looks fine as far as I can tell.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Startup of Webpack failed. Output was:
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module '@vaadin/build-status-plugin'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\webpack.generated.js
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel.watson\git\data-loader-web\webpack.generated.js:16:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\webpack.generated.js',
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\daniel.watson\\git\\data-loader-web\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}

    com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.doStartDevModeServer(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:217)
    com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.runOnFutureComplete(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:169)
    com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.lambda$new$0(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:160)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:479)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Comment: Have you done a "deep" clean (depends on your build tool, but usually involves just removing everything incoding node_modules etc)?

Comment: I would try running `mvn vaadin:clean-frontend` (which will remove `node_modules`, `package.json` and ``package-lock.json`).

Comment: I see the same problem, but with the initial starter app, not in a upgrade situation.
Any ideas or recomendations for nodejs etc. components?